# Row count for dynamic query in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server

I have a dynamic query which will have UPDATE statements. These statements can update up to million records. To avoid database lock I want to update them in batch. My confusion is, I am using `EXECUTE sp_executesql` and not sure how to get row count of it.

SQL Code:

```
DECLARE @ConcatQueryString NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ConcatQueryString = COALESCE(@ConcatQueryString + ' ', '') + CAST(Query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) FROM TableName

EXECUTE sp_executesql @ConcatQueryString
```

@ConcatQueryString:

`UPDATE TableName SET Value = 852 WHERE Description  = 'Description1' AND ConceptID  = 404 UPDATE TableName SET Value = 853 WHERE Description  = 'Description2' AND ConceptID  = 404`

Issue:

How to use `@@ROWCOUNT` to get the record count of all `UPDATE` statements so that I can use it for batch update? In above example there are two `UPDATE` staements and I want total row count of both of the queries.

Comment: keep a running total after each `update`. `@TotalCount = @TotalCount + @@ROWCOUNT` and then return via an out parameter. See help for `sp_executesql` for how to pass parameters.

Comment: Could you elaborate `To avoid database lock I want to update them in batch` and `get the record count of all UPDATE statements so that I can use it for batch update`? How is rowcount related to a "batch"? not sure what you saying about the batch but I'd suggest to cover multiple updates with a single transaction and probably to escalate lock to a whole table. I really miss the point of words about avoiding database lock during millions of updates.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance That's what I wanted. Thank you.